# inserir dados de um usuário em uma tabela de acordo com sua escolha em um <select> (PHP)

Tags: php

Tenho esse html e de acordo com a escolha do usuario, inserir em uma tabela no banco de dados:

```
<select name="tipousuario" id="tipo_usuario" placeholder=" selecione o tipo de usuariousuario">
    <option name="medico" value="medico"> medico </option>
    <option name="paciente" value="paciente" > paciente </option>
</select>
```

e o seguinte arquivo php:

```
<?php
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $novasenha = $_POST['novasenha'];
    $nascimento = $_POST['nascimento'];
    $tipousuario = $_POST['tipousuario'];
    $CRM = $_POST['CRM'];
    $RG = $_POST['RG'];

    $conexao = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "helpsus") or die("Nao foi possivel conectar ao Banco de Dados: ");

    if ($tipousuario == "medico") {
        $inserir = "insert into medico values ('$CRM', '$nome', '$novasenha', '$nascimento')";

    } elseif ($tipousuario == "paciente") {

        $inserir = "insert into paciente values ('$nome', '$usuario', '$novasenha', '$nascimento')";
    }

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao ,$inserir);
?>
```

só que ele não insere nunca na tabela paciente; só funciona quando no select é escolhida a opção "medico".

Comment: posta foto da tabela paciente

Comment: Tenta isto `$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao ,$inserir) or die(mysqli_error());` e diga qual a mensagem de erro.

Comment: exta exibindo  algum erro na rela ? deve ter erro na sua query

Comment: cara sempre que for fazer inserte é bom  definir os campos que vai inserir nem sempre quando poe no  modo  automatico os campos estão  na orde então insert into tabel(campo, campo) values(valor, valor)